# Avoid zombies when father is in a wait of a semaphore

Tags: c, signals, semaphore, wait, zombie-process

This is a strange question. I have 2 different program:
server and client.

server start, alloc all the message queue and start to waitin for a signal from client (the signal is for tell to the server that "there are new message").
the server remain in an infinite loop until recive SIGQUIT.
the client, when casted, start to send a huge number of message to the server

```
  for(;;){//infinite loop
    wait(sem,1); //wait for new message
    rc = msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &qbuff); 
    seq_num++; 
    pid=fork(); //new process for take the message
    if(!pid){
            if((msgrcv(msgid, &q, msgsz, 1,MSG_NOERROR))== -1) 
                perror("msgrcv error");
            else{
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //start  critic sector
                printf("\nthere is a prenotation\n");
                q.price=get_conf_value(q.kindof_service)+(q.priority*get_conf_value(3)); //costo = costo_visita + (priorità * costo_priorità)
                q.turn=seq_num-q.priority; //assign turn
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //end critic sector
                if(q.turn<0)q.turn=0; //controllo del turno che non sia minore di 0
                printf("---------------------------");
                printf("\nPrenotation number %i\npid caller: %i\npriorità: %i\n for %i\ncost %i\nturn %i\n",seq_num,q.clientId,q.priority, q.kindof_service ,q.price, q.turn);
                printf("---------------------------\nPrenotation ok\n\n\n");
                }
    printf("\nsuccess.\n");
    exit(1); //close children process
    }
    }
```

The problem is that, in this way the father leave so much zombies. If i add

```
        else{//i am the father
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }
```

there is the problem that the primary process fork, then wait until the child is ended, then fork again.
i need that the father fork so many time and that dont wait the end of the process before fork again.

But without the waitpid the problem is another.. because after that he start all the process needed for receive all the message, the father take the control and still waitin for another signal from the client (the first wait(sem,1) ), leaving so much zombie process.

I don't know if I explained it well.. is very difficult in english -_-

So, i want a server that, received the signal, fork many many times. any child take a message and do some stuff, then the child end. Meanwhile the server continue to wait for new incoming message. All without make zombies :)

Comment: What you want is to create a new process for each message you receive, or, you want to have multiple process to receive multiple messages simultaneously?

Comment: I want a new process for each message that I receive!

Comment: Oh, and i must say that i can run client many time, all togheter, then one mesasge, then start 3 client sending 10 message each

Comment: Try change the order between fork and msgrcv. First receive the msg, and later fork to process it, without using the waitpid.

Comment: Don't change.. The problem still that any call to the client, make a server process zombies.. Because the Main Server take control before that the child is ended, and it still in the wait for the semaphore..

Comment: How do you initialize your mutex? and your "sem"?

Comment: In the right way, trust me! I read a lot and watch much example on that!
I dont think it's a problem of semaphore and/or mutex, just because the Server create only few zombie, the other process still end correctly (ex. for 50 messages, only 22 zombies, but all the messages is received and evaded)

Answer (score 1):

One way to fire-and-forget processes without having to worry about zombies is to fork twice.

Each process has a parent process. If the parent process exits before the child does, the child is becoming an orphan, and is inherited by `init` (process 1) - which will wait for all children, preventing them to become zombies without manual work.

So what you can do is to fork, and fork yet again in the child process. Then, you can let the child exit, which will cause the grandchild (where you do your work) to be inherited by `init`. The parent process can `wait` for the child (which won't take long, because the child did nothing else than fork and exit). When the grandchild is exiting, `init` will automatically `wait` for it.

```
/* fire and forget */
int execute_detached(char **cmdline)
{
  pid_t pid;

  if((pid = fork()) < 0) { /* fork error */
    perror("fork");
    return 0;
  }
  else if(pid > 0) {       /* parent */
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    return 1;
  }
  else {                   /* child */
    if((pid = fork()) < 0) { /* fork error */
      perror("fork");
      return 0;
    }
    else if(pid > 0) {     /* child */
      /* make grand child an orphan */
      _exit(0);
    }
    else {                 /* grand child */
      execvp(cmdline[0], cmdline);
      perror("execvp");
      _exit(1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```